# How does "[[" work as a function in sapply?

Tags: r

From the mtcars dataset, we can get the first word of the rownames by using:

```
a = strsplit(rownames(mtcars), " ")
```

Then by using sapply, we can get the first word of each element of a.

```
sapply(a, "[[",1)
```

My question is how does that even work? How does "[[",1 work as a function in sapply?
[I found this in a plotly example while looking for a way to make a donut chart](https://plot.ly/r/pie-charts/)

Comment: We should migrate this to stackoverflow.com since it' off-topic in here.

Answer (score 1):

It works because `[[` is a *function* that extracts element of given index from a list, see [`?"[["`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).